# Can I view tags from other languages without switching my store language?

Tags: steam

I use Steam in Finnish as I'm one of the voluntary translators for that language. As a result, my store is in Finnish as well and I only see tags made by other users who are using Finnish. Unfortunately there are approximately 3 people doing that, so not many games have tags other than the very generic "Free to play" and similar. The English version of the store usually has more tags giving more information about the game.

Can I see the tags from other languages without changing my Steam language setting?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. On the official steam website it says you can browse tags categorized in your language. I also contacted the steam support and they told me the same. So I'm afraid but you would really have to change your language.